# Definition of Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I'm a little bit confused by the definition of a martingale. We say that a sequence of RV's is a martingale if:

$E[X_n|X_{n-1}]=X_{n-1}$.

I'm confused because it seems like the LHS should be just a number since we are taking an expectation while the RHS is a random variable, i.e., a function. How does it make sense grammatically to say that they are equal?

Comment: $E[X|Y]$ is not a number but a function of $Y.$

Comment: All this is saying is that the expected value of the next guess is the previous guess.  Brownian Motion is a classical example:  If you are allowed to move only right or left, and you decided which step to take by flipping a (fair) coin, then the expected value of your $(n+1)$-st step is precisely your $n$-th position.

Comment: Conditional expectations *are* indeed random variables.

Comment: $E[X_{n+1}|X_n=x]$ is the average value of $X_{n+1}$ over the event $\{X_n=x\}$. This is a function of $x$, because $x$ determines the event you are averaging over. Call this function $g(x)$. Then $E[X_{n+1}|X_n]$ is just equal to $g(X_n)$, which is indeed a random variable.